# Terminal font is buggy

Tags: 10.10, command-line, fonts

After my fresh install of Ubuntu 10.10, I noticed that the terminal's font is smashed together and altogether awful-looking.

Does anyone have a solution or workaround? I've been trying to find one for a few days. :(

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you have the new Ubuntu font set as your terminal font. This is not recommended, because the monospace version of the Ubuntu font has not yet been created.

To reset yourself to the default terminal font then run the following in a terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --unset /desktop/gnome/interface/monospace_font_name
```

You can also do this graphically, in System->Preferences->Appearance->Fonts. Here change the "Fixed width font" to 'Monospace' size 10. It will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir! That fixed things. It's a shame they haven't created an ubuntu version for it yet. Is there a bug report filed? I should probably go file one. :-/

Comment: It's a pleasure to help. Don't bother, it's already a well know issue (expect it in time for the next Ubuntu release!): http://launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+milestone/monospace

Comment: Aww "Expected: 2010-12-15". If I knew how/what to code in, I would work on it right now to help 'em out. xD (I only know some java)

Answer (score 6):

Use a different font. The new Ubuntu font is not a monospace font, so it looks screwed up in the terminal (which expects monospace).  I think Inconsolata is a great monospace font.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for helping me out, man. It is much appreciated. :)